# How to Ask a question which is a continuation

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, ethics

How to ask a question if it is a continuation of a question I asked before?

Should I edit my question and ask, or ask that as a new question?

Comment: Why `are` you randomly `using` backticks??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask a new question. If necessary, you can add a link to the old question to provide background information. Try to keep your new post self-contained though.

The old question was once a question for you. If someone else has the same question, that person may not be helped by the new question that has taken the old question's place.

Also, answers to the old question may not be answers to the new question, and loose their context.

Answer (score 6):

If your existing question is answered but as a result your now realise there are new, additional problems then that is a new question and should be asked separately (you can link to the original question to give background but the question must "stand alone"). This is an appropriate thing to do for several reasons;

- It avoids invalidating previously good answers that helped you, doing so creates a confusing state for the question if the answers are not updated, is impolite because it 'obliges' the people who posted answers to update and removes clearly useful answers from the internet
- It creates 2 questions for two different situations, some other people may have one of your two problems but not both; as such two seperate questions may be more helpful
- [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are notoriously difficult to answer to the satisfaction of the question asker and often potential answers will simply abandon them; preventing you (or anyone else) getting your answer.

On the other hand if it's simply a clarification to the current question then edit that in